# Compiling a working 32bit .dll for 64bit, errors

Tags: windows, dll, 64-bit

I have with a lot of help put together a 32bit plugin (.dll) for the 32bit Teamspeak program which works great.

People are now asking me to compile this for the 64bit Teamspeak client.

But...........
When I do I get the following errors.

```
     1>------ Build started: Project: GetFSComFreqs, Configuration: Release x64 ------
     Creating library C:\Users\Roo\Desktop\pluginsdk\src\x64\Release\GetFSComFreqs.lib and object C:\Users\Roo\Desktop\pluginsdk\src\x64\Release\GetFSComFreqs.exp
     GetFSComFreqs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SimConnect_Close referenced in function "void __cdecl DLLStop(void)" (?DLLStop@@YAXXZ)
     GetFSComFreqs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SimConnect_Open referenced in function "void __cdecl DLLStart(void)" (?DLLStart@@YAXXZ)
     SimConnectProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SimConnect_Open
     GetFSComFreqs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SimConnect_CallDispatch referenced in function "void __cdecl DLLStart(void)" (?DLLStart@@YAXXZ)
     SimConnectProcs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition referenced in function "void __cdecl OnRecvOpen(struct SIMCONNECT_RECV_OPEN *,unsigned long,void *)" (?OnRecvOpen@@YAXPEAUSIMCONNECT_RECV_OPEN@@KPEAX@Z)
     SimConnectProcs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SimConnect_RequestDataOnSimObject referenced in function "void __cdecl OnRecvOpen(struct SIMCONNECT_RECV_OPEN *,unsigned long,void *)" (?OnRecvOpen@@YAXPEAUSIMCONNECT_RECV_OPEN@@KPEAX@Z)
     SimConnectProcs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SimConnect_GetNextDispatch referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl MessageRoutine(void *)" (?MessageRoutine@@YAIPEAX@Z)
     C:\Users\Roo\Desktop\pluginsdk\src\x64\Release\GetFSComFreqs.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
     ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

A part of the Code...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define FSAPI __stdcall

HANDLE hSimConnect = 0;
HANDLE hMsgThread = 0;
HINSTANCE ThisModule = 0;
HRESULT hr = 0;
char ThisModuleName[MAX_PATH];

void FSAPI StartSimConnect()
{
if (NULL == hSimConnect)
    {
    GetModuleFileName(ThisModule, ThisModuleName, MAX_PATH);
    hr = SimConnect_Open(&hSimConnect, ThisModuleName, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hr = SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, SimConnectDispatch, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) hSimConnect = 0;
    else hMsgThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, NULL, MessageRoutine, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

void FSAPI StopSimConnect()
{
if (NULL != hSimConnect)
    {
    hr = SimConnect_Close(hSimConnect);
    hSimConnect = 0;
    }
}

int main() {}
void FSAPI  DLLStart(void)
{
if (NULL == hSimConnect)
    {
    GetModuleFileName(ThisModule, ThisModuleName, MAX_PATH);
    hr = SimConnect_Open(&hSimConnect, ThisModuleName, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hr = SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, SimConnectDispatch, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) hSimConnect = 0;
    else hMsgThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, NULL, MessageRoutine, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

void FSAPI  DLLStop(void)
{
if (NULL != hSimConnect)
    {
    hr = SimConnect_Close(hSimConnect);
    hSimConnect = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, where do the various `SimConnect_*` functions come from?  In other words, how did you make the 32-bit version work?

Comment: The SimConnect functions are coming from SimConnect.lib.
It seems I'm having problems with my Linker as I've just tried to build a totally different project and that too isn't seeing files I have added to the linker.

Comment: OK, so you need to link the 64-bit version of your problem with the 64-bit version of SimConnect.lib.

Comment: Ah now I've just found my problem then and I'm about to show my lack of dev skills.
SimConnect.lib is only available as 32bit

Comment: Is there a way I could compile as 64bit using a 32bit .lib?

Comment: No, that isn't possible.  You can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in the same process.  The first step has to be to obtain or build a 64-bit version of simconnect.lib, or to rewrite your code so as to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting *unresolved external symbols errors.*

If all those `SimConnect_*` functions are coming from an external source, you need to link you program with the appropriate *import library*.

If you just changed the build configuration from *win32* to *x64*, it might be the case that these *import libraries* were not changed into your *x64* configuration.